# Bonding, multiplicity and quantum chemistry for FeP2

Tags: electronic-configuration, quantum-chemistry, crystal-structure

I’m trying to do some quantum chemical calculations for the linear molecule $\ce{FeP2}$ in the gas phase as well as its crystal ([orthorhombic symmetry like here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0031-8949/4/3/010)). I am lead to believe that in both cases iron has an oxidation state of +6, and phosphorous has an oxidation state of −3. My questions are:

- Are such oxidation states a reasonable assumption for this molecule?
- Would the molecule normally be a singlet (multiplicity of one)?
- What quantum chemistry methods would be appropriate for this system?

Comment: While I find your question interesting, I'd also very much like to see your thoughts on the questions you pose and where exactly you have problems.

Comment: P.S. Welcome to Chem.SE!

Comment: Are my problems not clear from the question? I am mainly concerned with the oxidation state and spin configuration that could be assigned to this system, and aslo what minimal method from quantum chemistry I should use to tackle it.

Comment: The reference you provided states that FeP2 has marcasite-like structure. Marcasite is FeS2 polymorf with S2 units and Fe(II), so marcasite-type FeP2 likely has Fe(IV) This is a high value, but reasonably common for Fe-Ni in sulfide neighborhood, so FeP2 may have said formal oxidation state (since P is close neighboor of S). I would be very hesitant to use it for any consideration, though, since P is not very electronegative, so the real charge of Fe is likely very low.

Comment: Your reference also specifically states that Fe has $d4$ configuration, it corresponds to +4 oxidation state.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread. You are conserned about the molecule. Did you tested triangle geometry? It may yet prefer this form. As for QC method, in my experience gaussian pbe/6-31g* is enough for qualitative calculations.

Comment: @permeakra I am pretty certain, that PBE is not enough for this system, not even qualitatively, especially when you try to find the correct spin state. A multi reference method is well advised. At least a hybrid functional it advisable in any case.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン For in-depth investigation with multiplicity search I'd prefer at least MP2 with triple-split basis and even it maybe not enough. For qualititative investigation *in my experience* involving d-elements, pbe works well enough and incresing basis abouve 6-31g* is pretty useless for this imprecise functional. I fully admit, I the systems I have experience with maybe not representative for this particular case.

Comment: @permeakra Unfortunately MP2 will fail horribly for this system, because small HOMO-LUMO gap can be expected (pretty common for the iron group). In other cases I would agree with you on the qualitative level, but whenever it comes to transition elements, one has to be a lot more careful. \*sigh\*

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly it is vacuum phase, but are you certain about your oxidation state assignments?  "nearly temperature independent susceptibility of -(8.8±0.7)centerdot10-6SI (at room temperature)"

doi:10.1016/j.jpcs.2013.04.015 
https://sciborg.uwaterloo.ca/~lfnazar/publications/Electrochem_Solid-State_Lett_6_8_A162-A165_2003.pdf  
doi:10.1021/ja301173q  
http://www.staff.uni-bayreuth.de/~bt220235/refs/HPR_29_235.pdf  
doi:10.1088/0031-8949/4/3/010 (given)

Comment: No, I am not sure at all. That is why I would like to do some calculations, and also why I raised the question... any other suggestions?

Comment: You might write an orbital diagram for the elements and push   electron population into reasonable configurations. I'm happier with Fe(II). Elemental phosphorus is not a strong oxidizing agent. However, Vacuum phase has its own rules.

Comment: Can phosphorous have an oxidation state of -1 in such phosphides?